# How to inject URL query string parameters in Python?

Tags: python, query-string

I want to compose an equivalent debug URL for any URL of my organization's website. I have Python function to do this:

```
import urlparse
import urllib

def compose_debug_url(input_url):
    input_url_parts = urlparse.urlsplit(input_url)
    input_query = input_url_parts.query
    input_query_dict = urlparse.parse_qs(input_query)

    modified_query_dict = dict(input_query_dict.items() + [('debug', 'sp')])
    modified_query = urllib.urlencode(modified_query_dict)
    modified_url_parts = (
      input_url_parts.scheme,
      input_url_parts.netloc,
      input_url_parts.path,
      modified_query,
      input_url_parts.fragment
    )

    modified_url = urlparse.urlunsplit(modified_url_parts)

    return modified_url



print compose_debug_url('http://www.example.com/content/page?name=john&age=35')
print compose_debug_url('http://www.example.com/')
```

If you run the code above, you should see the output:

```
http://www.example.com/content/page?debug=sp&age=%5B%2735%27%5D&name=%5B%27john%27%5D
http://www.example.com/?debug=sp
```

Instead I expect:

```
http://www.example.com/content/page?debug=sp&age=35&name=john
http://www.example.com/?debug=sp
```

It's because `urlparse.parse_qs` returns a dict of strings to lists rather than a dict of strings to strings.

Is there another way to do this in Python more simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urlparse.parse_qs` returns **a list** of values for each key. In your example it's
`{'age': ['35'], 'name': ['john']}`, while what you want is `{'age': '35', 'name': 'john'}`.

Since you're using key, value pars as a list, use [`urlparse.parse_qsl`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl)

```
modified_query_dict = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(input_query) + [('debug', 'sp')])
```

Comment: Thanks. `urlparse.parse_qsl` behaves as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but [`urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) takes a `doseq` parameter which can be used to flatten the list.